# how to limit an article and add Read More button which on clicking creates a new link in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am making a site as project for me to learn coding. A small article posting site. On the main page I want to have 5 to 6 articles with limited text of different Categories. I have some question related to it;

1-    How to create a Read More button witch on the event of clicking create a new page and redirects to it with JQuery.

2-    I have a simple HTML form through which I would post articles. I want, whenever I publish new article it skips the older one down and take its position.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Your questions are too generic, maybe if you add some of your code people can help you better.

Comment: I can add my front end code of html and CSS but my questions are different with respect to code @AdriánBolonio

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a Read More button witch on the event of clicking create a new page and redirects to it with JQuery.

You cannot create new files with Javascript/jQuery. JavaScript runs in client side. You could save it to the server though by sending it through an AJAX request so you will need some backend (server side) logic to do this.

To redirect to a new file/page in javascript try:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

> I have a simple HTML form through which I would post articles. I want, whenever I publish new article it skips the older one down and take its position.

One idea is making it with jQuery. Imagine you have some DOM structure like this one:

```
<div id="post_container">
  <div id="post_1" class="post">
    <h2>Post Title 1</h2>
    <p>Post description 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="post_2" class="post">
    <h2>Post Title 2</h2>
    <p>Post description 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use in jQuery something like

```
$( "#post_button" ).click(function() {
  // First generate the html structure with the data obtain from the posting form.
  var newPost = "<div id="post_3" class="post"><h2>Post Title 3</h2><p>Post description 3</p></div>";
  // You can prepend it to the post_container
  $("#post_container").prepend(newPost);
  // Or append it if you want different behaviour
  // $("#post_container").append(newPost);
});
```

If you want to delete the older post you can hide the div with the higher post_id

Source:

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/